# Restrict CLI Deployment for environment Laravel Vapor

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

Good Day.

I am trying to place restrictions on deploying to specific environments from CLI for specific members of my team.

I am happy for them to deploy to our Dev environment locally but I would like to place restrictions on them doing so with regard to our Staging and Production Environments.

I have read the documentation and tried to apply these restrictions through the CLI and the dashboard but it seems as though I can only restrict deployments across all environments for a single user.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this is simply not possible.
Vapor (laravel/vapor-core V2.0) only allows you to apply permission per user across all projects and environments as per a discussion I had with one of the support technicians. The permissions you can edit exist under the Team Settings menu on the Vapor Dashboard. These permissions apply to a specific user for all projects and their respective environments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).